# Compare grouped by rows on a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a list of different amounts, and I want to group these amounts from different sources to see if they match. So my table looks something like this:

```
id   name  amount description startDate            endDate              location type sourceId linkId   isMatch
A111 name1 111.11 desc        2019-06-06T00:00:00Z 2019-06-06T00:00:00Z location a    INTERNAL A111X111 True
A111 name1 222.22 desc        2019-06-06T00:00:00Z 2019-06-06T00:00:00Z location b    INTERNAL A111X111 True
A111 name1 555.55 desc        2019-06-06T00:00:00Z 2019-06-06T00:00:00Z location a&b  INTERNAL A111X111 True
A111 name1 444.44 desc        2019-06-06T00:00:00Z 2019-06-06T00:00:00Z location a    EXTERNAL A111X111 True
A111 name1 444.44 desc        2019-06-06T00:00:00Z 2019-06-06T00:00:00Z location b    EXTERNAL A111X111 True
```

I can group them like so:

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  a.id,
  SUM(a.amount) AS total,
  a.description,
  DATEDIFF(day, a.startDate, a.endDate) AS days,
  a.location,
  a.sourceId,
  a.linkId,
  a.isMatch
FROM
  DataHistory a
GROUP BY
a.name, a.id, a.description, DATEDIFF(day, a.startDate, a.endDate), a.location, a.sourceId, a.linkId, a.isMatch
```

To get almost what I want:

```
name  id   total  description days location sourceId linkId   isMatch
name1 A111 888.88 desc        0    location EXTERNAL A111X111 True
name1 A111 888.88 desc        0    location INTERNAL A111X111 True
```

But what I want is to have a column with the difference between the two amounts (internal and external) and so I actually want these two records to appear on a single line (and also because there will actually be many such pairs of these records). In the example, the difference is zero, but I am going to be looking for the cases when the difference is not zero. It could be that there are no external or internal records (hence 0 for the amount), or just that the amounts sum up to different amounts. I thought about perhaps inserting the grouped records to a temp table and then trying some sort of self-join, but I am not sure if this will work in all cases, and it definitely doesn't seem efficient if I actually have many such records.

I also created a SQL Fiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7a5ff3/1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: put sourceid into group by

Comment: @cuongle Hi cuongle. I am not sure what you mean? In the sample query I gave, the sourceId is in the group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, drop `sourceId` from `group by` and from `select` and sum all total, but for `external` take `-a.amount`. That will give you the difference:

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  a.id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.sourceId = 'INTERNAL' THEN a.amount ELSE -a.amount END) AS total,
  a.description,
  DATEDIFF(day, a.startDate, a.endDate) AS days,
  a.location,
  a.linkId,
  a.isMatch
FROM
  DataHistory a
GROUP BY
a.name, a.id, a.description, DATEDIFF(day, a.startDate, a.endDate), a.location, a.linkId, a.isMatch
```

Answer (score 1):

You need pivoting. As you are grouping anyway, conditional aggregation is most natural way to go

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  a.id,
  SUM(CASE a.sourceId WHEN 'INTERNAL' THEN  a.amount ELSE 0 END) AS totalINTERNAL,
  SUM(CASE a.sourceId WHEN 'EXTERNAL' THEN  a.amount ELSE 0 END) AS totalEXTERNAL,
  a.description,
  DATEDIFF(day, a.startDate, a.endDate) AS days,
  a.location,
  a.linkId,
  a.isMatch
FROM
  DataHistory a
GROUP BY
a.name, a.id, a.description, DATEDIFF(day, a.startDate, a.endDate), a.location, a.linkId, a.isMatch
```